# Using Balancing Groups to match custom nested structure in configuration file

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

I have files that store fields in nested structures using BEGIN and END keywords. For example,

```
BEGIN Root_Name

    var1 = 0
    var2 = "string"
    var3 = "string"

    BEGIN node1
        var = "string"
        var= 1

        BEGIN node2
            var = 1
        END

        what_about_me = "??"
    END
END
```

My regex is able to first match the entire tree structure from *Root_Name* until its matching *END* up until *node1*. If I pass the string from node1 until its end, however, then my regex will only match up until the very first *END*. (i.e. it will fail to capture the what_about_me variable) I had learned about balancing groups recently and I was wondering how I could use it to fully recurse down the tree.

Here is the regex I'm currently using for matching the root tree and the subroot. (The differences are ^ and $ to anchor the values)

```
$AnchoredDelimiter = "(^(BEGIN)(\s+)((`".*`")|((\w|_|-)+))[\r\n]*)" 
$AnchoredClose = "((?-i)^END(\t| )*)" 
$Root = "$AnchoredDelimiter$Body$AnchoredClose"

$Delimiter = "((BEGIN)(\s+)((`".*`")|(\w|_|-)+)[\r\n]*)" 
$Body = "((.|[\r\n])*?)"
$Close = "((?-i)END(\t| )*)"  
$SubRoot = "$StandAlone$Delimiter$Body$Close"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex

```
$Delimiter = "(((?-i)BEGIN(?i))(\s+)((`".*`")|(\w|_|-)+)[\r\n]*)"
$Close = "((?-i)\bEND\b(?i))" 
$Root = "(?m)$Delimiter(?<Contents>(?>\s|(?<Delimiter>$Delimiter)|(?<-Delimiter>$Close)|.)+?(?(Delimiter)(?!)))$Close"
```